# Determining BDC for V6?

Tags: engine

Need help sussing out something.  The background: I have a 3.0 Ford Vulcan V6 in a 2000 Taurus (a 60º V6).  Was changing spark plugs, the hex for piston #2 broke off above the threads.  Gonna try using a square-cut extractor to remove the remains stuck in the head, but I need to set the piston at BDC first.

How can I use the position of pistons 4-6 (because they are more easily accessible) to determine when piston #2 is BDC?

Found this diagram online:

[image]

The firing order is supposedly 1-4-2-5-3-6.  So if I start with #1 at TDC, the cylinder fires, rotates the crank 60º, moving #4 to TDC and firing *it*, then rotating 60º, rotating #2 to TDC and firing it, and so on?
I believe the TDC-BDC pairings should be like this, correct?

1-5

4-3

2-6

5-1

3-4

6-2

So if I want to set #2 to BDC, I should rotate the crank so that #6 is at TDC.  Right?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the pairs will be 1&4, 2&5, 3&6 as they will be on the same crank throws...